# Using a specific glyph with a webfont

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Using a webfont, I would like to use the ***font-feature-settings:*** option in CSS along with a ***span class*** in HTML in order to use a specific alternate glyph from the font set.

Which values (GID, Unicode?) do I need to use in correct syntax in order to target a specific `glyph` within the `glyph` alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These features use OpenType Stylistic Alternates (salt). From the glyph panel in Illustrator, we are shown that this is Stylistic Alt number 4 (granted, it’s not very clear what that means without additional context).

If your CSS, you might add a class for each Stylistic Alternate:

```css
/* OpenType Stylistic Alternates */
.salt,
.salt-1 { font-feature-settings: "salt"; }
.salt-2 { font-feature-settings: "salt" 2; }
.salt-3 { font-feature-settings: "salt" 3; }
.salt-4 { font-feature-settings: "salt" 4; }
```

Then, in your HTML:

```html
<h1>
  <span class="salt">C</span>offee
</h1>
```

And using a specific number:

```html
<h1>
  <span class="salt-4">C</span>offee
</h1>
```

[image]

You might also decide to just apply the Stylistic Alt to the entire word, but this can have different results depending on the font:

```html
<!-- Apply the OpenType feature to specific letters -->

<div>
  <span class="salt-1">C</span>offee
</div>

<div>
  <span class="salt-2">C</span>offee
</div>

<div>
  <span class="salt-3">C</span>offee
</div>

<div>
  <span class="salt-4">C</span>offee
</div>

<!-- Apply the OpenType feature to whole words -->

<div class="salt-1">
  Coffee
</div>

<div class="salt-2">
  Coffee
</div>

<div class="salt-3">
  Coffee
</div>

<div class="salt-4">
  Coffee
</div>
```

If you’d like to learn more about OpenType features on the web, you can check out my [Utility OpenType CSS library](https://github.com/kennethormandy/utility-opentype), and other resources on the “further reading” at [the bottom of the documentation](http://utility-opentype.kennethormandy.com/).